# Is where a link goes part of a view use case?

Tags: uml, use-case

Say I got a minimal use case such as "view home page" or "view banner ad". Should it be included or exluded in the use case actually following the link? What I mean is that whether it belongs to the use case "view page 1" if a report is that "The link from page 1 to page 2 is not working" in the common case of a "link not working".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, use cases should not concern themselves with implementation details such as links, home pages or banner ads. If you have a use case for delivering a report, then that use case should be equally satisfied if the report is hand-written and delivered by an office clerk, if it is a multi-page PDF document or if it is a collection of web pages with navigation links.

The only place where a good use case would refer to technology is in describing the alternative scenarios of what might go wrong. And even there I would not mention broken links, as they can occur anywhere. Such errors are better dealt with in generic requirements outside the context of a use case.

Besides the behaviour related requirements that can be described very well with use cases, each project will invariably have some requirements that don't really fit the pattern of a use case, such as non-functional requirements and functional requirements that apply to a large portion of the use cases. You should *not* try to force these requirements into the pattern of a use case, but rather let them stand alone as non-use case requirements.